# Stop TinyMCE Image Tools plugin renaming image file to imagetools.jpg

Tags: image, rename

Anyone any idea why TinyMCE image tools plug-in in keeps renaming my images like 'imagetools.jpg' when I edit an image ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that you need the option in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
images_reuse_filename: true,
```